# Is there a way to get a Masters Degree in CS/IT in the USA while at the same time working part-time?

Tags: usa, visa, working-visas, student-visa, us-citizens

As a family man currently settled in the Philippines, I want to further my Software Engineering career and success for my family (I want to do it along with my wife and baby as I don’t want to miss his early years). Is there a way to get a Masters Degree in CS/IT in the USA while at the same time working part-time to sustain my family needs? I want to explore H1B as an opportunity in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Working for the university you are attending in some limited capacity (say, <= 20 hours/week) is generally possible.

Comment: Which US visa will allow this sir to take my family together with me and allow me to work while taking part-time Masters Degree in the USA?

Comment: In addition, I suppose part-time study is permissible in H-1B status.  @youinc Student visas and H-1B visas both have provision for dependents.  For example, dependents of a J-1 visa holder can apply for J-2, and dependents of an H-1B holder can apply for an H-4.

Comment: You  have to be a full-time student if on a F-1 visa, so the part-time work will be in addition to a full course load. That's usually around 12 credit hours.